# Entity Framework with Oracle command Add-Migration creates in the table key field of the decimal type, but in the template is integer

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, migration, database-migration

Because when I run `Add-Migration Test -Force` command, it generates the create table in the table it places as decimal, whereas in the model it is int "id_usuario = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0, identity: true),"

```
public partial class Teste : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.sec_usuarios",
            c => new
                {
                    id_usuario = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0, identity: true),
                    id_cidade = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
                    nome_completo = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id_usuario);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.sec_usuarios");
    }
}
```

See my model with the property `public int id_usuario { get; set; }`:

```
[Table("sec_usuarios")]
public class usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int id_usuario { get; set; }

    public int id_cidade { get; set; }

    public string nome_completo { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Context

```
public class Contexto: DbContext
{
    public Contexto() : base("Contexto")
    {  }

    public DbSet<usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SYSTEM");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I do not know why this occurs, where can I determine by default int? Is there an intermediary?

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with your code..Have you tried different db (sql server), just to validate. At first I was thinking a setting on oracle db but seems unlikely and a bit far fetched. I have no oracle db i could try but this looks weird

Comment: I have experience with mysql and I have no problem, only with oracle this occurs